# NotNullViolationError: Enable foreign key to be None while saving object to DB

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

Having two objects `PLaylist` and `PlaylistEmbedding` both use DB to setup their ID and the embedding is part of playlist

```
class Playlist(SQLModel, table=True):
    playlist_id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    embedding_id: int = Field(foreign_key="playlistembedding.embedding_id")

class PlaylistEmbedding(SQLModel, table=True):
    embedding_id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    playlist_id: int = Field(foreign_key="playlist.playlist_id")
    embedding: list[float] = Field(sa_column=Column(Vector()))
```

I wanted to save both objects to the DB:

```
    async with get_async_session() as session:
        session.add(playlist)
        await session.flush()
        assert playlist and playlist.playlist_id

        playlist.embedding_id = await get_embedding_for_playlist(playlist)
        await session.merge(playlist)

        await session.commit()
```

But keep getting error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.NotNullViolationError'>: null value in column "embedding_id" of relation "playlist" violates not-null constraint

- How to save those two objects in one-to-one relation with their IDs defined by DB?
- What to do to save first `Playlist` object -> get its ID from DB -> save `PlaylistEmbedding` object with the returned from db ID of `playlist_id`-> update the playlist object with the ID of saved `PlaylistEmbedding` object?

I tried replacing flush with commit but no change

Comment: Why do both of the tables need a foreign key to each other? It looks like its the same relation you are trying to describe there?

Comment: Even if I eliminate the embedding-> playlist direction I still get the error:
'sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.NotNullViolationError'>: null value in column "playlist_id" of relation "playlistembedding" violates not-null constraint'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need foreign keys on both sides
2. Create relationship `playlist_embedding: "PlaylistEmbedding" = Relationship()` to have the ability to insert both linked objects in one time
3. When you create objects, link them using relationship field (`playlist_embedding`)

```
from typing import Optional
from pgvector.sqlalchemy import Vector
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Column, Relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, exc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


class Playlist(SQLModel, table=True):
    playlist_id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    embedding_id: int = Field(default=None, foreign_key="playlistembedding.embedding_id")

    playlist_embedding: "PlaylistEmbedding" = Relationship()


class PlaylistEmbedding(SQLModel, table=True):
    embedding_id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    embedding: list[float] = Field(sa_column=Column(Vector()))


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


with session_maker() as session:

    # Successful case
    emb = PlaylistEmbedding(embedding=[0.1])
    pl = Playlist(playlist_embedding=emb)

    session.add(pl)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(pl)

    print(f"{pl.playlist_id=}, {pl.embedding_id=}")


    # And it will still get exception if you don't specify embedding_id field
    emb = PlaylistEmbedding(embedding=[0.1])
    pl = Playlist()
    session.add(pl)
    try:
        session.commit()
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        print("`embedding_id` is still required field")
```

Output:

```
pl.playlist_id=1, pl.embedding_id=1
`embedding_id` is still required field
```